# C# MongoDB ranking base on points array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Working on the latest C# mongodb driver and .NET 4.5.1.

I want to conduct some custom made competetions between players.
Assuming I have the following model.

```
public sealed class PlayerPoints
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId PlayerId;

    public DateTime CreateDate;

    public int Points;
    public int[] SeasonalPoints;

}
```

I want to be able to get the rank of a player/s between specific `SeasonalPoints` indexes.

An example:

```
 {PlayerId : someId1, CreateDate : <someCreateDate>, Points : 1000, SeasonalPoints : [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]}
 {PlayerId : someId2, CreateDate : <someCreateDate>, Points : 1000, SeasonalPoints : [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,50,150,100]}
 {PlayerId : someId3, CreateDate : <someCreateDate>, Points : 1100, SeasonalPoints : [200,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,0,0,300]}
```

Note that there are 10 seasons here.
Im searching for a query which returns a sorted list of the players according to their rank. The rank is set by the sum of the points between a provided indexes.

If I query for rank in season 9 to 10 then someId3 is first, someId2 after and someId1 is last.
If I query for rank in season 7-9 then someId1 is first, someId2 is second, someId3 is third.

I thought about using aggregation, How will it affect performance on around 1m documents while also this query will be called very frequently.

**Clarification**

The main question is how to build this query which will yield the above results, the secondary question is how much performance the query will consume from the server.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your current "query" for reference?

Comment: @EyalPerry look at the description Ahi

Comment: I read your question Ya Ah, and it does not clearly specify that you're looking for a query, what I derived is that you have a mongo C# API query, and simply wish to use aggregation framework instead, and that the question regards to performance. Can you please clarify what exactly you're asking? I would love to help.

Comment: @EyalPerry i hope ive made it clearer

Comment: You have. I will answer you ASAP, I just fear that it might not be today.

Comment: @EyalPerry just reminding you :)

Comment: I remember. Just having a crazy time and I want to provide you with a runnable and optimal solution.

Comment: Havne't forgotten about you. I almost have it ready. Sort is thorwing excpetions at me. Excpet for that I have the data in good form. Hang on and sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Eyal Perry Im having the same difficulties. I thought about serializing the object differently to support such a thing but unfortunatly im not very familar with this and its side effects

Comment: See my edited answer below. Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: See my latest edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the very least, if the machine on which the server is hosted is not the same as the database's machine, you will get improved server performance.

On the other hand, this may mean that the database machine could be less "available", since it is too busy computing the aggregation result. this is something that should be benchmarked, as it varies from application to application, and from time to time.

This depends on user loads, data amount, host machines, etc.

As for the query, here is a program which I verified to actually work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace MongoAggregation
{

public sealed class PlayerPoints
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    //Note that mongo addresses everything as UTC 0, so if you store local time zone values, make sure to use this attribute
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public int Points { get; set; }
    //note that your model did not allow a player to not participate in some season, so I took the liberty of introducing a new sub document.
    //It is better to create sub documents that store metadata to make the query easier to implement
    public int[] SeasonalPoints { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //used v 2.4.3 of C# driver and v 3.4.1 of the db engine for this example
        var client = new MongoClient();
        IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("agg_example");

        var collectionName = "points";
        db.DropCollection(collectionName);

        IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
        IEnumerable<BsonDocument> data = GetDummyData().Select(d=>d.ToBsonDocument());

        collection.InsertMany(data);

        //some seasons to filter by - note transformation to zero based
        var seasons = new[] {6, 7};

        //This is the query body:
        var seasonIndex = seasons.Select(i => i - 1);

        //This shall remove all un-necessary seasons from aggregation pipeline
        var bsonFilter = new BsonDocument { new BsonElement("Season", new BsonDocument("$in", new BsonArray(seasonIndex))) };

        var groupBy = new BsonDocument// think of this as a grouping with an anonyous object declaration
        {
             new BsonElement("_id", "$_id"),//This denotes the key by which to group - in this case the player's id
             new BsonElement("playerSum", new BsonDocument("$sum", "$SeasonalPoints")),//We aggregate the player's points after unwinding the array
             new BsonElement("player", new BsonDocument("$first", "$$CURRENT")),// preserve player reference for projection stage
        };

        var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending(doc => doc["playerSum"]);

        var unwindOptions = new AggregateUnwindOptions<BsonDocument>
        {
            IncludeArrayIndex = new StringFieldDefinition<BsonDocument>("Season")
        };

        var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Expression((doc => doc["player"]));

        List<BsonValue> sorted = collection
            .Aggregate()
            .Unwind(x=>x["SeasonalPoints"], unwindOptions)
            .Match(bsonFilter)
            .Group(groupBy)
            .Sort(sort)
            .Project(projection)
            .ToList();

    }

    private static IEnumerable<PlayerPoints> GetDummyData()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new PlayerPoints
            {
                CreateDate = DateTime.Today,
                SeasonalPoints = Enumerable.Repeat(100,7).ToArray()
            },
            new PlayerPoints
            {
                CreateDate = DateTime.Today,
                SeasonalPoints = new []
                {
                    100,100,100,100,100,150,100
                }
            },
            new PlayerPoints
            {
                CreateDate = DateTime.Today,
                SeasonalPoints = new []
                {
                    100,100,100,100,100,0,300
                }
            },
        };
    }
}
}
```

Comment: well, there are sitting on different machines. but i also need the query, i dont have it

Comment: the model's properties are kind of similar to what i have in production, can we put alil more time into it to check if there is a way where i dont have to modify the array there? it might be an issue for me

Comment: I will look into it.

Comment: It seems like its gonna work..im having some issues though.. im getting an $unwind field path must be specified as a string exception.
since my collection has implicit type i have to write Unwind(x => x.SeasonalPoints, options) and it seems to be an issue..
ill still accept cause i understood the thinking. if you want to help, give me a msg :). although, ive created another reference to my collection using the BsonDocument type and it still throws an error

Comment: probably cause mongo 3.0.x

Comment: I would love to help man. Either way, you must upgrade to 3.4.. they have added amazing capabilities.

Comment: nvm. i could update my deployment to 3.2.1 successfully. but no results. still investigating..

Comment: Happy to help, gever.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below aggregation with `3.4` version.

Aggregation Stages - `$project` - `$sort` - `$project`.

Array Aggregation Operators - `$reduce` & `$slice`

Arithmetic Operator - `$add`

Example :

> If I query for rank in season 9 to 10 then someId3 is first, someId2
>   after and someId1 is last

The below code will use `$project` stage to keep `PlayerId` and `TotalPoints`.
 `

`TotalPoints` uses `$slice` with `SeasonalPoints` array with starting position of `9` and returning up to `2` elements followed by `$reduce` which takes the array values and sum the value for each document.

`$sort` stage to sort descending on the `TotalPoints` value.

`$project` stage to output the `PlayerId` value.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        IMongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("db");
        IMongoCollection < PlayerPoints > collection = db.GetCollection < PlayerPoints > ("collection");

        var pipeline = collection.Aggregate()
            .Project(p => new {
                PlayerId = p.PlayerId, TotalPoints = p.SeasonalPoints.Skip(9).Take(2).Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + s2)
            })
            .SortByDescending(s => s.TotalPoints)
            .Project(e => new {
                e.PlayerId
            });

        var result = pipeline.ToListAsync();

    }
}
```

Mongo Shell Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "PlayerId": "$_id",
        "TotalPoints": {
            "$reduce": {
                "input": {
                    "$slice": ["$SeasonalPoints", 9, 2]
                },
                "initialValue": 0,
                "in": {
                    "$add": ["$$value", "$$this"]
                }
            }
        },
        "_id": 0
    }
}, {
    "$sort": {
        "TotalPoints": -1
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "PlayerId": "$PlayerId",
        "_id": 0
    }
}])
```

Comment: unfortunatly this throws "Aggregate of type System.Linq.Enumerable is not supported in the expression tree"

Comment: I have just tested with 2.4.3 version and it works for me. https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/CSHARP-1662. 2.4.x supports aggregate.

Comment: Yes I did. The shell query posted is the generated  from c# code. You are using 2.4 driver version  and 3.4 mongo version right ?

Comment: driver 2.4.3 and im pretty sure mongo version 3.0.1

Comment: i updated my driver, just to be sure and not i received another failure:Command aggregate failed: exception: invalid operator '$reduce'."

Comment: Yep it's not 3.4 server. Can you upgrade mongo server too ?

Comment: our db-server is hosted on a 3rd-party. ill ask them and reply asap

Comment: Unfortunatly i cannot upgrade to 3.4at the moment. Any ideas?

Comment: you really need at least server 3.2 to be able to manage array values the way you need to.